# Jquery UI autocomplete: find on value, but add only key to input line

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have returned json array like:

```
{key:123,value:"Kyiv"},
{key:5675,value:"Ukraine"},
{key:456,value:"Poland"}
```

I need to find names in value field, but after clicking on some value to input line must be added only key value.

P.S. Sorry if i created dublicate question, but i can not find solution on this site. If related thread isset, please give me link, please.

Answer (score -1):

The JSON Object you provided is invalid in his syntax ! Your key should be a string. Furthermore those are 3 JSON Objects autosuggest only takes one you should wrapp that in an array. You can simply check if your JSON is valid on http://jsonlint.com/. Your valid syntax would be:

```
[
    {
        "key": 123,
        "value": "Kyiv"
    },
    {
        "key": 5675,
        "value": "Ukraine"
    },
    {
        "key": 456,
        "value": "Poland"
    }
]
```

Comment: I know it. My code is not invalid. This only fragment for example.

Comment: Downvoted, as it does not really provide an answer to the question.

Comment: but I provided a solution to a part of his problem, it appeared to be a problem at least.+

Comment: Solution is very simple: instead of 'key' name, need using 'label' variable. UI Autocomplete searching in label value, but to input line putting variable from 'value' line.